# Wordpress - WP_Query posts_where filter on custom table

Tags: wordpress, where-clause

My first ever post as I've been stuck on the below for some time now.
I am trying to join onto two custom tables and then add a where statement to the query
I believe the joins are working correctly as if I edit data in the database I can get posts to knock out correctly which do not have assigned staff or appointments.

My problem currently is the where filter either seems to bring back everything or give a 404 error site wide.

I am trying to achieve "If there is an active appointment for X date then do not show post / listing for this staff member" which would knock out their post / listing from search results and making them invisible on that date and only return listings for staff members who have no appointments for the given date.

After alot of googling I think maybe I need an array with between dates?
If anyone could advise I would be very thankful

This is what I currently have for which the join filter works but where filter does not

```
    $date = $_GET['date'];
    $date = date($date);

    // Format 2023-12-24 00:00:00
    $date_time_start = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime($date));
    // Format 2023-12-24 23:59:00
    $date_time_finish = date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('+23 hour +59 minutes',strtotime($old_date)));


    add_filter( 'posts_join', 'add_other_table_staff', 10, 2 );

    function add_other_table_staff( $join, $wp_query ) {
            
            global $wpdb;

            $join .= " JOIN my_staff as staff on staff.wp_user_id = {$wpdb->posts}.post_author ";

            return $join;

    }

    add_filter( 'posts_join', 'add_other_table_appointments', 10, 2 );

    function add_other_table_appointments( $join, $wp_query ) {
            
            global $wpdb;

            $join .= " JOIN my_appointments as appointments on appointments.staff_id = staff.id ";

            return $join;

    }

    add_filter( 'posts_where', 'where_other_table', 10, 2 );

        function where_other_table( $where, $wp_query ) {
    
            // If a single post then return
            if(is_single()){
            return $where;
    }else{
    
               $where .= " AND appointments.start_date !> $date_time_start AND appointments.end_date !< $date_time_end ";

            return $where;

    }}
```